# position input next to input

Tags: css, input, position

on this [page](http://www.gioventunyc.com/new-page/) I'm trying to position the "subscribe" box next to the input box.

so far i've floated all three `left`, but the final element isn't in the correct spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to tidy up your HTML, but failing that, this will do it:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe-form .mc-field-group {
padding-bottom: 0; 
}

#mce-responses {position: absolute;}

#subscribe {margin-left: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `clear` class will remove the floating. If you remove that class the subscribe box will appear next to the input box. You will probably need some negative top margin or something similar to line it up correctly.

Comment: ah. if i can't remove that (it's something i copied from mailchimp and not sure if it will break the input form) is there another solution? or do i need to get rid of it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp states that clear will not allow any floating elements to either side.

Answer (score 0):

look at this at css

```
input {
display: inline-block; 
}
```

That's why it isn't working the way you want.

Comment: what should it be instead?

Comment: In my opinion this `display: inline-block;` display the input in another line. So simply delete it all `input { other stuff but display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 0):

By giving the `div` with id `subscribe` the class `clear`, it inherits `clear:both`. You need to remove it.

Meanwhile, also remove `padding-bottom` from `#mc-embedded-subscribe-form .mc-field-group`.

This should line up the button correctly.